# Existing IIS log player/browser

Tags: c#, iis

I host a website and I can access to its IIS log.
I'd like to find a way to replay users sessions from a kind of browser if possible, in order to check what users see on screen.

Does it exist a way to do this from code (c#, visual studio)? Or do you know an application that does the job?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is beyond what IIS logs can do/are for.

Comment: In IIS settings, you can add custom fields as QUERY_STRING or PATH_INFO, so you can guess what users do.

Comment: Yes but that's not what you want, at least not from your description, sounds more like you want to record screen input and replay. That's not what web logs are for. Web logs deal generally with the basic request details.

Comment: Actually, if I can find a way to "replay" GET and POST requests, it can be fine. Replaying ajax request could be fine also, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/) would help you to monitor the application's users session.